# react-native-paper DataTable text style

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

How can I style text in react-native-paper?

I have a dark mode in my app and need light colors for my texts.

I could use a theme, but in my app I am only using this one component from React Native Paper, and besides, I already have a theming in place.

```
   <DataTable.Cell style={{color: "#fff"}}> // <-- This styling does not work
      Sophia Loren
   </DataTable.Cell>
```

The above code does not change the font color as for all DataTable components the style prop is of the type [ViewStyle](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table-cell.html#style), which means it does set, for instance, the background color, but not the font color.

Comment: DataTableCell uses the default text styles of react native paper. So you can change the color by changing the react-native-paper's theme https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html Specifically `colors.text`

Comment: Thank you, Uğur, but, as said above I would rather not using Paper's theming. Is there any other solution involving only the component?

Comment: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/main/src/components/DataTable/DataTableCell.tsx#L59 As seen in the source code, DataTable.Cell uses the default Text component of react-native-paper and it doesn't have a style prop. But you can add a prop yourself like `textStyle` and make sure it stays in place with patch-package https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Answer (score 2):

I found a very simple solution: nesting a Text component.

```
  <DataTable.Cell style={{ flex: 0.5 }}>
     <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}> // <-- This style works!
        Sophia Loren
     </Text>
  </DataTable.Cell>
```

Answer (score 2):

The text in the DataTable cells of React Native can be styled by using the prop called "textStyle".
Refer to the [documentation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/data-table-cell.html) for more details and examples.

```
<DataTable.Cell textStyle={{fontFamily:"Avenir", fontSize:20}}>Ice cream</DataTable.Cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution

```
<DataTable.Title key={1} textStyle={{fontSize:20}}  > 

</DataTable.Title>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 <DataTable.Title><Text style={styles.texting}>Tests</Text></DataTable.Title>
```

Comment: There are a number of answers to this question already. Are you sure this hasn’t been given? If so, why do you prefer this approach?